# How to pull out specific elements in a json file and store them in another dictionary? How to properly Iterate through dictionary/json file?

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary, object

I have a Json file that I am trying to pull out certain values and not touch some of the others. The only way I can seem to pull out values is by appending them to a list, which I can only access one key at a time. Theres a whole bunch of nested dictionaries and within each dictionary I need to  pull out 3 key/value pairs, add them to a new dictionary and use on of the elements as the key.

```
original_dict = [{'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 300, 'd': 400, 'e': 500}, {'a': 101, 'b': 201, 
'c': 301, 'd':401, 'e': 501}, {'a':102, 'b': 202, 'c': 302, 'd': 402 'e': 502}]
data = []
for i in original_dict:
    data.append(i['b'])
```

this doesn't work at all, I am completely lost but know how I need the final product to operate. I need the value of 'd' to be the key in the new dictionary for the values 'a' and 'b' of its old dictionary. It should look something like
{400: 100, 200}, {401: 101, 201}, {402: 102, 202}

When I try doing the .append I cant grab multiple values/key in the same dictionary while iterating, I need a new method.

Answer (score 0):

```
output_dict = {}
for _dict in original_dict:
    output_dict[_dict["d"]] = [_dict["a"], _dict["b"]]

{400: [100, 200], 401: [101, 201], 402: [102, 202]}
```